# Understanding deref function in Rust book

Tags: rust

I'm going through the [Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#treating-a-type-like-a-reference-by-implementing-the-deref-trait) section of the Rust book and I have questions about the `deref` function.

```rust
struct MyBox<T>(T);

impl<T> Deref for MyBox<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

Question 1. If the input parameter (`&self`) is already a reference to `T` why do I need another `&` when accessing `0` in the body of the function? Wouldn't that create a pointer to the pointer of self `&&self` which would be redundant?

Question 2: The following `deref` function below does not compile but if I did the same in the main function it compiles.

```rust
fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
    // let my_box: &MyBox<T> = self;
    let my_box: &&MyBox<T> = &self; 
    //this does not compile with either of the above two my_box references
    //it asks for another `&`.
    my_box.0 
}
```

The code above compiles when used in main function.

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_box: &MyBox<i32> = &MyBox(5);
    my_box.0;
}
```

Comment: after 4 years of Rust I still fear to write `Deref` word. Your first question is ABC, it should be explain in the book.

Comment: Is `Deref` a dangerous area in Rust programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: `&self` is a reference to struct `MyBox` itself, not its inner field. `self.0`'s type is T, and this is the actual inner field. To make the return type `&Self::Target` match, you need `&self.0` (meaning `&(self.0)`) whose type is `&T`.

Q2: Same as Q1, you need to make the type match. `main` function's return type is `()`, and the last statement `my_box.0;` (notice `;`)'s type matches.